# :q!Symfony4 Autowiring not wofking for own Utils

Tags: php, autowired, symfony4, php-7.2

I'm trying to access TokenStorageInterface inside a Utils Class, since I need to reuse code and I don't want to mess with internal logic inside the controllers.

But I get the following error when accessing the TokenStorage Interface from my class.

*Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Utils\Ability::__construct(), 0 passed*

Here is my class (I'll post just the __construct since that's the relevant part) :

```
<?php
namespace App\Utils;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class Ability
{    
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }
}
```

Any clues?

PS: Autowiring is enabled

Adding config\services.yaml :

```
parameters:
    locale: 'en'

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false       

    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

Comment: You might want to add the relevant parts of your service configuration and controller accessing the service.

Comment: Added the service configuration and made it more generic, Just trying to use doctrine inside the service. Same problem